# Create alert for the resource group

Tags: azure

We want to create metrics alert (CPU usage) on resource group, but the only one available option is to create alert for particular VPS. We have hundreds of VPS.

Is it possible to create one alert on all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to create one alert on all of them?

For now, we **can't** via Azure portal to set one alert for all of them.

As a workaround, we can use PowerShell command `Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule` to create alert rule.

First we should use PowerShell to list all VMs' resource ID, then use `foreach` to create alert rules for them.

About how to use PowerShell to create alert rules, please refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cloud_solution_architect/2016/02/26/retrieving-resource-metrics-and-creating-alert-rules-via-azure-powershell/).

Comment: may be possible with OMS Log Analytics + Alert Management though, but I need to check.